# iOS Chrome Browser / Chromecast Compatibility

Tags: chromecast

My team is prototyping a Chromecast app and would like to take advantage of the [supposed support](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/2014/07/chrome-for-ios-update.html) in v36 of the iOS Chrome browser.  Casting on a new Android Chrome browser is automatically enabled, but we can't find any corresponding features in the Chrome version.  We tried to access them here with no luck:

```
chrome://flags/#enable-cast
```

Has anybody had any luck at all enabling casting from iOS Chrome?  We're not finding any more detailed information than the bit in the Chrome releases blog I linked to above.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no exposed API for that, you need to [file a support ticket](https://support.google.com/cast-developer/contact/google_cast_contact_us?hl=en&rd=1) and ask your question there.